# How can fuzzy logic be applied to computer language design?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, fuzzy-logic

Is fuzzy logic in any way applicable to general-purpose language design? If yes, then how would a computer language theoretically benefit from first order support of fuzzy logic?

Comment: What do you mean by "fuzzy logic"?

Comment: @MilkyWay90 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic